# Setting a python prompt title a random string

Tags: python, windows

I am new to python and I'm having a little issue where I can't manage to set a title of a command prompt to a random string.

I know how to print random strings but don't really know how to implement it in a title bar.

```
import random
import string

letters = string.ascii_lowercase
print ( ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(10)) )
```

this above was pretty easy to find out.

I tried:

```
letter =  string.ascii_lowercase
os.system("TITLE " + random.choices(letter))
```

and

```
letter =  string.ascii_lowercase
tit = random.choices(letter)
os.system("TITLE " + tit))
```

but none of this worked.

In c++ I did it like this:

```
std::string RandomString(const size_t length)
{
    std::string r;
    static const char bet[] = { "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzZ1234567890" };
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL) * 5);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        r += bet[rand() % (sizeof(bet) - 1)];
    return r;
}
int main(main, char**)
{ 
SetConsoleTitleA(RandomString(30).c_str());

//code
}
```

[it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sW5KO.png)

But I just can't manage to do it in python. Is it even possible and how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "but none of this worked." What happened when you tried it? How is that different from what is supposed to happen? Does it work if you try using the `os.system` line with a hard-coded string? Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. When you do `random.choices(letter)`, what result are you expecting? In particular, what do you expect will be the *type* of the result? Why? Did you try reading the documentation?

Comment: You say that you already can create and print a random string with `''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(10))` Did you try using this way with the `os.system` trick? If not, why not? If so, what happened?

Comment: Hey, thank you!
I should've read How to Ask before asking. My bad. Also, I tried it but kind of in a wrong way. Didn't know I had to add `' '` before '.join(...)' and also it didn't give me any error, it would just end the program. Thank you for warning me, I will make sure to not make these kind of mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ctypes` module that is included with Python to call C APIs in DLLs.

From the [SetConsoleTitle docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoletitle), the function is available in `kernel32.dll`.  For APIs that take strings they typically have an `A` version and a `W` version, which take ANSI and wide strings, respectively.  For Python, the `str` type is passed as a wide string, so prefer the wide version:

```py
import random
import string
import ctypes as ct
from ctypes import wintypes as w           # defines many Windows types as ctypes types.

dll = ct.WinDLL('kernel32')                # DLL where API is found
dll.SetConsoleTitleW.argtypes = w.LPCWSTR, # sequence of argument types
dll.SetConsoleTitleW.restype = w.BOOL      # return type

letters = string.ascii_lowercase
title = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(10))
print(dll.SetConsoleTitleW(title))  # returns 1 (TRUE) on success
input('Press Enter to continue.')  # title may change back after Python exits.
```

Note: `os.system` will work in this case, too, but use `input()` to pause Python.  Once it exits it may change back to command prompt default.  It did for me, even for a C version.  The command prompt sets the title constantly, at least with Windows 10.

Comment: You can also use `''.join(random.choices(letters, k=10))` to avoid the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track with *this* code, but in the second line...

```
letter = string.ascii_lowercase
os.system("TITLE " + random.choices(letter))
```

You'll want to modify how you grab random letters so you can create a window-title-safe string out of the list [`random.choices()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) creates. Here's an example snippet of code that works for me, you can modify `k=` to change the length of the randomized string.

```
os.system("title " + "".join(random.choices(letter, k=5))) # 5 character long random string as the title.
```

Comment: Windows shell commands should be case-insensitive; but yes, the problem is that `random.choices` creates a list, not a string (and also, it only gets one choice by default, unless you tell it how many). This is the best answer, but I think the question should have been closed as due to a typo - OP knows the relevant pieces of information, and doesn't appear to have *tried* the various combinations of approaches *already known*, nor tried to *understand* the problem any further than "it doesn't work" - not reading, or even showing us the error message.

Comment: Good to know! I'll edit my post to clear that up, and I'll also include an explanation for why the issue with the random choices occurs, which I should've done in the first place.